# Update value of INPUT in externally loaded FORM not working

Tags: javascript, validation, input, url-parameters

total programming novice here - I don't know much of javascript, wasn't programming since university (about 10 years ago) - trying to solve one specific problem on my website.

I am using CRM Bitrix24 and I have an unsubscribe form from this CRM placed on my website. I need to setup the form the way that the email is loaded from URL parameter.

I have done that simply by loading the input and set `input.value = "email from URL"`. My problem is that the form has some kind of validation, and even though there is a text filled in the input field, the form is giving me the error: **Field is required.**

Screenshot here: https://ibb.co/Ns33GVN

The code of external form look like this:

```
<script data-b24-form="inline/120/8y7xg2" data-skip-moving="true">(function(w,d,u){var s=d.createElement('script');s.async=true;s.src=u+'?'+(Date.now()/180000|0);var h=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];h.parentNode.insertBefore(s,h);})(window,document,'https://cdn.bitrix24.com/b7014957/crm/form/loader_120.js');</script>
```

My JS:

```
function emailPopup(){
var params = new window.URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var email = params.get('email');

    const emailCollection = document.getElementsByName("email");
    for (let i = 0; i < emailCollection.length; i++) {
      if (emailCollection[i].name == "email") {
          //emailCollection[i].focus();
          emailCollection[i].value = email;
      }
    }
} window.addEventListener('load', function () {
 emailPopup();
})
```

I tried to understand how the validation is done, but with no luck. The field has autocomplete = yes, so once it is submitted, next time it's not shooting the error, but the form is sent with the email submited at the first attempt, even though it is showing another one when hitting the SUBMIT button. It seems like it's only showing the email address from URL parameter, but in fact it's using wrong value, it's even empty (first attempt) or wrong (second attempt).

Is there a way how to force the field to pretend it was modified by user? Any ideas?

I have tried to setup similar environment here in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e395wf6m/17/

Thanks a lot for any feedback!

Comment: The external form is loaded asynchronously because of `s.async=true`. So the form elements aren't loaded yet when your code runs.

Comment: Yeah - this is something I was fighting with, but resolved by: `window.addEventListener('load', function () {
 emailPopup();` 
If this would be the problem, then the field would be empty, but it's showing the URL parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I have a theory and it seems to be correct, as I tested it in your fiddle.

My theory is that the validation is done by firing a change event, so you need to trigger it. Luckily JavaScript let us do it:

```
if (emailCollection[i].name == "email") {
      //emailCollection[i].focus();
      emailCollection[i].value = email;

      // to trigger the change event
      emailCollection[i].dispatchEvent((new Event('change'))); 
  }
```

As I said, it worked when I tested it on your fiddle, let me know if it works for you =]

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I might do something wrong, but it's not working for me on website, nor in fiddle, here is the short exhibition of what I did: https://youtu.be/jYhibnuUeTM

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, try using "input" instead of "change" and see if it works

Comment: You rocks Bruno! Thanks a lot, I wasn't able to find a solution half of the day yesterday and you resolved it so fast, thanks a lot, it's working like glimps! 

Comment: You're welcome! It's my pleasure to help =]